# Issues of using "SequenceFilesFromDirectory" in my code

Tags: java, eclipse, mahout

I am trying to write a sample program that can call use the main method of "SequenceFilesFromDirectory", which aims to convert a set of files into sequence file format.

```
public class TestSequenceFileConverter {
public static void main(String args[]){   
String inputDir = "inputDir";   
String outputDir = "outoutDir";
SequenceFilesFromDirectory.main(new String[] {"--input",
        inputDir.toString(), "--output", outputDir.toString(), "--chunkSize",
        "64", "--charset",Charsets.UTF_8.name()});
}
}
```

But the Eclipse tells me that what I did was wrong with the following error message

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Syntax error on token "main", = expected after this
>        token
>       - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
>       - SequenceFilesFromDirectory cannot be resolved

I think I did not use this method correctly, but I don't know how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

The following is how the SequenceFilesFromDirectory defines. The API link for SequenceFilesFromDirectory is http://search-lucene.com/jd/mahout/utils/org/apache/mahout/text/SequenceFilesFromDirectory.html

Comment: Do you have the relevant import statement for `SequenceFilesFromDirectory` and is it in your classpath?

Comment: I copied every import statement for SequenceFilesFromDirectory to my java code of TestSequenceFileConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're missing an import line from the first section of your file:

```
import org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory;
```

Comment: Hi, I just added this import statement, but the error message changes to "unhandled exception type Exception".

Comment: @user873766: Okay, so now you need to either catch the exception yourself, or declare that your `main` method throws `Exception`. Have you done any Java before? Stack Overflow is great for specific questions, but it can't really take the place of an introductory book or tutorial.

Comment: @John, I am learning java while trying to use Mahout. I solved this issue by adding "try...catch". What confuses me is that why "try...catch" is required for this scenario.

Comment: @user873766: Because `Exception` (declared by `SequenceFilesFromDirectory.main`) is a *checked exception*. I would personally advise you to learn the basics of Java *without* any third party libraries - but with a good book to tell you about things like checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your purpose for using SequenceFilesFromDirectory is to convert doc files to sequence files. If so, better to call the run()/runSequential()/runMapReduce() methods ater creating an object of SequenceFilesFromDirectory, because SequenceFilesFromDirectory.main() internally calls haddop ToolRunner.run() method for processing.
Whereas the run methods of SequenceFilesFromDirectory do the actual processings.